# How to use "setFont" in jsPDF with UTF-8?

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My project: Angular 7

I want to add custom font (UTF-8) to my service that generate PDF. I use jsPDF. I found many examples but all doesn't work for me. On GitHub jsPDF documentation says (chapter Use of UTF-8 / TTF):
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

It means that I can do that. So I generated this file (font Roboto-regular.tff). But where I should paste this file and how to use it?

Answer (score 8):

This is simple:

1. Create a function `somePDFCreator` and check your available fonts `console.log()`:

```
     import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

     function somePDFCreator() {
          const doc = new jsPDF();
          console.log(doc.getFontList());
        }
```

2. Add your generated `font Roboto-regular.tff` from this website: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html
   and insert IIFE js code to `somePDFCreator`. Check in the log, there must be your font.

```
    import jsPDF from 'jspdf';   

    function somePDFCreator() {
       (function (jsPDFAPI) { var font = 'AAEAAAAQAQAABAAAR......';
       var callAddFont = function () {
         this.addFileToVFS('Roboto-regular.tff', font);
         this.addFont('Roboto-regular.tff', 'Roboto-Regular', 'normal');
       };
       jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
       })(jsPDF.API);


       const doc = new jsPDF();
       console.log(doc.getFontList());
    }
```

3. Use your imported font `doc.setFont('Roboto-Regular', 'normal');`:

```
    import jsPDF from 'jspdf';   

    function somePDFCreator() {
       (function (jsPDFAPI) { var font = 'AAEAAAAQAQAABAAAR......';
       var callAddFont = function () {
         this.addFileToVFS('Roboto-regular.tff', font);
         this.addFont('Roboto-regular.tff', 'Roboto-Regular', 'normal');
       };
       jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
       })(jsPDF.API);


       const doc = new jsPDF();
       console.log(doc.getFontList());

       doc.setFont('Roboto-Regular', 'normal');
       doc.setFontSize(8);

       doc.text("Example text Lorem ipsum", 40, 25);
       return doc.save('myPdfFileName.pdf');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  look at the docs carefully, it asks you to process your ttf file and use the generated js file alongside your applications code.

> The 14 standard fonts in PDF are limited to the ASCII-codepage. If you want to use UTF-8 you have to to integrate a custom font, which provides the needed glyphs. jsPDF supports .ttf-files. So if you want to have for example chinese text in your pdf, your font has to have the necessary chinese glyphs. So check if your font supports the wanted glyphs or else it will show a blank space instead of the text.
>
> To add the font to jsPDF use our fontconverter in /fontconverter/fontconverter.html . The fontconverter will create a js-file with the content of the provided ttf-file as base64 encoded string and additional code for jsPDF. You just have to add this generated js-File to your project. You are then ready to go to use setFont-method in your code and write your UTF-8 encoded text.

reference: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF#use-of-utf-8--ttf

I hope that solves your issue!

Comment: How does jsPDF recognize my font js file after I add it to the project? I assume I need to use addFont() but can't really figure out since addFont() receives postScriptName, id, fontStyle, encoding as params but I don't know where to find them

Comment: @DuongNguyen After adding the js script, you can call the `jsPDF.setFont('MyFont')` function to set the text to your custom font. http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#setFont