# jsPDF: How to render Ä Ü Ö?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF to create a pdf file from a webpage. I like to add a text but if use ä ö ü it won't be rendered correctly.

I tried to add Unicode characters to my pdf using the documentation, but the docs they have added for the library related to the Unicode part doesn't include any examples. It would be great if you could provide an example.

This is my code:

```
function doDocData(doc) {
    var number_of_pages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages()
    var pdf_pages = doc.internal.pages
                                                    
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');//optional
    for (var i = 1; i < pdf_pages.length; i++) {
        doc.setPage(i)
                           
        var strl = 'I like to add Ä Ü Ö';
        doc.setFontSize(10);// optional
        doc.text(strl, 20, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);//key is the interal pageSize
                            
        var str = 'Seite ' + i  + ' von ' +  number_of_pages;
        doc.setFontSize(10);// optional
        doc.text(str, doc.internal.pageSize.width - 80, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);//key is the interal pageSize
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For utf-8 encoded Characters like Ä, Ö, Ü you need to include a font, that is utf-8 encoded (like it is stated in the Documentary: [Use of Unicode Characters / UTF-8](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/)) since jsPDF by default contains only ASCII font.
A font like this ([ARIAL utf-8](https://wiki.processmaker.com/sites/default/files/arialuni.ttf) ATTENTION: opens download of arialuni.ttf) can be converted by jsPDF own [fontconverter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html).
You can find a code example how to include the converted font here: [setFont in jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627570/how-to-use-setfont-in-jspdf-with-utf-8/60592877#60592877?newreg=5fc8e834b29447af9d5ab150d18c8a75)

Comment: Please update your reply to include important information from the stated resources, as links tend to break over time.